# How can I set my site so users can sign in with metamask?

Tags: html, ethereum, web3js, metamask

Currently, my site uses Passport.js so users can sign in with facebook & google, etc. but I want users to be able to sign in to my site with Metamask and be able to send ETH (and other cryptos) to each other. I've seen some crypto-based sites enable users to sign in with Metamask to interact with their Dapp but I only want users to be able to send direct transactions to each other when their username is shown in the chat.

Is there a simple way for users to sign in to my site with Metamask and be able to send each other crypto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you want to achieve is implemented on [CryptoKitties](https://www.cryptokitties.co/).

What you need to do is to prove the ownership of an account by signing a piece of data using a private key.

I've found this [tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial) which you can follow for its complete implementation.